# How to set cron job url in codeigniter on HostGator cpanel

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

Actually i want to run cron job in my application that is made on HostGator cpanel but my url is not working properly.

```
wget www.luvkushfinserve.com/Blog/auto_cron
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to run it in each 5 minute on daily basis then add it like -

```
* /5 * * * wget www.luvkushfinserve.com/Blog/auto_cron
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
php index.php welcome show
```

as command in your crontab. E.g.:

```
0 * * * * php /home/username/index.php welcome show
```

Source (ver. 2.2.0) http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/cli.html

Source (ver. 3.*) http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html